# Hive Hadoop cluster - hive clients inconsistent view of databases

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop, hive, hdfs, cluster-computing

Hi I have a hadoop cluster consisting of 5 Ubuntu machines.

Each machine can successfully store and retrieve files from HDFS(Hadoop Distributed File System), and maintain a consistent view of HDFS files.

When creating databases through hive, hive clients on different machines can not see each other's databases, even though they can find the table files in /user/hive/warehouse/`<databasename>`.db/`<tablename>` on HDFS.

I was wondering how to enable cross client resource sharing for hive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://dzone.com/articles/how-configure-mysql-metastore

Basically, install mysql server. Set up the config files in hive to use the Thrift protocol to contact the mysql server, with query params to create the metastore db on first connect, delete existing metastores in local file system for each data node.

Then it should work across the cluster.